# Mongodb take keys array listi

Tags: php, mongodb

I use mongoDB and I have this collection:

```
{
"_id" : ObjectId("5810020c63b46a3071029031"),
"where" : "shool",
"referenceWork" : [ 
    {
        "role" : "teacher",
        "people" : [ 
            {
                "name" : "lello",
                "num" : "01"
            }, 
            {   "name" : "gigi",
                "num" : "02"
            }, 
            {
                "name" : "mario",
                "num" : "03"
            }
        ]
    }, 
    {
        "role" : "janitor"
    }
]
```

}

I need know how to get the keys of the array, like : teacher and janitor.

My php commands:

```
$query = "db.people.findOne({'_id' : ObjectId('".$id."')})"; 
$response = $db->execute($query);
$responseJson = $response['retval']['referenceWork'] ;
echo json_encode($responseJson);
```

Also, I don't know how to get the referenceWork length.

Comment: Did you read any documentation of php and mongodb? Please Read first. 
Here is the official documentation  http://php.net/manual/en/mongo.queries.php

Comment: I did.i really don't know

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try the code below :-

```
        $rescursor=[];      
        $query = "db.people.findOne({'_id' : ObjectId('".$id."')})";
        $response = $this->getDB()->execute($query);
        $arrayRole=$response['retval']['referenceWork'];
        $count = count($arrayRole);
        for($i=0;$i<$count;$i++){
            echo $arrayRole[$i]['role'];
            echo "<br>";
        }
```